# Selenium (Keys.ENTER) is not performing

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running some tests for Django Channels that work when I do them manually but when I run the test via Selenium it does not seem to be pressing ENTER after it inputs the text (the text shows up fine), and if I press it on the keyboard from my side it works.

Code for the ActionChains function

```
def _post_message(self, message):
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(message, Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Not sure whether its related but the logs show me the following ERROR as well:

```
[10864:2712:0105/185426.868:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [18:54:26.867] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Thank you

Tried using RETURN instead of ENTER and also doing the text input and send key as separate commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `send_key(Keys.ENTER)` return was too quick and as such the key was not getting pressed in time before the field was actually filled.

I used a for loop with a small timer and alas it worked.

```
def _post_message(self, message):
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    for letter in message:
        action.send_keys(letter)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```